# Force update lightning-record-view-form

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordviewform

I have some fields from a record i display via `lightning-record-view-form`.

I have an Apex action invoked imperatively e.g. `myMethod().then().catch()`.
That action changes the field on my object.

When the method returns successfully, i want the data in `lightning-record-view-form` to update. I tried setting the recordId to `'banana'` and then setting it back to `recordId`, but that didn't work.

```
import STATUS_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/My_Object__c.Status__c";

export default class Whatever extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
@track status = STATUS_FIELD.fieldApiName;
doStuff() {
  doApex().then(r => { // update? }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

```
<template>
   <div if:true={recordReady}>
                <div>
                    <lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name={objectApiName}>
                        <span>Status</span>
    <!-- We don't specify the name directly coz i am in a managed package with a namespace -->
                        <lightning-output-field field-name={status} variant="label-hidden">
                        </lightning-output-field>
                    </lightning-record-view-form>
                </div>

<lightning-button label="Do Stuff" onclick={doStuff} name="do"></lightning-button>

 <template>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried setting the recordId to 'banana' and then setting it back to
>   recordId, but that didn't work

It is loading the record from cache and so the values will not be refreshed. If you wait for 30 seconds and do this, then the values will get refreshed from server.

As of today, we do not have a direct way of refreshing the record values in [LWC forms](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_get_user_input)  when we know that the record is changed in database. For comparison in Aura, we have something like [reloadRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/specification) in LDS.

**Workaround:**

You can use [refreshApex()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/apex) on [getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record) to manually refresh the cache immediately. You can refer to - [How to refresh wired service getRecord manually?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279516/how-to-refresh-wired-service-getrecord-manually). Since you are using record-view-form, it will be using the same cache as that of **getRecord** and so it will refresh the form automatically. Also, you can just use 1 field ***Id*** to refresh the form. Below is the code which will work:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['Account.Id'] })
account;

doStuff() {
    doApex().then(r => refreshApex(this.account)).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getRecordNotifyChange](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_get_record_notify)

> Fetch record updates for the specified record IDs and refresh the
> Lightning Data Service cache, providing your wires with the latest
> record data

```
import { getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

doStuff() {
 doApex().then(r => { 
  getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.recordId}]);
 })
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it does not give me the effect i want, does not cause all `@wire` properties to refresh. Updating `Id` via `updateRecord` works a treat for that.

Comment: This works nicely with lighting-record-*-forms (especially to update stale roll-ups values)

Answer (score 0):

Initially let recordReady variable be true on your button onclick set this to false bring in a spinner to get the loading effect once the response has come set this to true again and sore the response in a non trackable attribute and pass the value to the desired field on the onLoad() method  of record edit form which a better choice for the scenario . Tried it on my end I could observe pre-population.