# Refresh lightning-record-view-form in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

We have a requirement where we want to refresh the lightning-record-view-form in LWC component. Is there any standard way or JS hack to refresh the lightning-record-view-form in LWC component?

Comment: Do you want to refresh on any button click or you want to refresh in some intervals?

Comment: I want to refresh it on button click, which is present in another component.

Comment: [This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/281678/force-update-lightning-record-view-form) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Rahul. The solution in the given link worked for me.