# Refresh @wire getRecord Manually, refreshApex not working

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lds

I know this has been asked and appropriately answered [HERE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279516/how-to-refresh-wired-service-getrecord-manually). However I am wondering if this is possibly done differently now as I can not get that structure to work. My code is almost exactly the same as the original.

```
@track _getRecordResponse;


    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: USER_ID, fields: [PHOTO_URL_FIELD] })
    userRecord(response) {
        this._getRecordResponse = response;
        let error = response && response.error;
        let data = response && response.data;
        if (data) {
            this.userImage = data.fields[PHOTO_URL_FIELD.fieldApiName].value;
        } else if (error) {
            this.handleError(error);
        }
    }
```

I am updating the User Image through Apex (I am building a community page and there are a few additional requirements that the built in User Image component doesn't have)

```
save() {
    if (this.newImage && this.uploadType === "Account") {
        this.showSpinner = true;
        // "Create" new Account Image
        this.updateContentVersion(
            {
                Id: this.newImage.ContentVersionId,
                [ACCOUNT_FILE_TYPE_FIELD.fieldApiName]: "Account Image"
            },
            true
        );

        if (this.existingImage)
            this.updateContentVersion(
                {
                    Id: this.existingImage.ContentVersionId,
                    [IS_DELETED_FIELD.fieldApiName]: true
                },
                false
            );

        return;
    }

    if (this.newImage && this.uploadType === "User") {
        uploadUserImage({
            fileRecordId: this.newImage.ContentDocumentId
        })
            .then(() => {
                this.showSpinner = false;
                this.newImage = undefined;
                this.showModal = false;
                this.saveDisabled = true;
                refreshApex(this._getRecordResponse);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.handleError(error);
                this.saveDisabled = true;
            });
    }
}
```

Once I manually refresh the page, the data updated in "uploadUserImage" renders without issue. I just need to of course programmatically refresh the getRecord wire

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please update the example of the usage where you have the imperative call to uploadUserImage so it shows the full context? I'm just wondering if the "this" binding is incorrect...

Comment: As to the "if this is done differently now" question, not that I'm aware of. We use this pattern still with the latest platform release.

Comment: @PhilW Updated with full context of uploadUserImage apex call

Comment: Even the callback will not be invoked if there is no change in field values. check [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/279529/70823) answer

Comment: @salesforce-sas I did see your response under PhilW but the Photo_URL_Field is being updated by uploadUserImage

Comment: Did you try debugging in the browser to see if the save method is called and confirming that the refreshApex call actually happens?

Comment: @philW Yes, refreshApex certainly happens, I believe i've stumbled upon the issue. I am using the UserProfile connect API class, specifically the SetPhoto method (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_UserProfiles_static_methods.htm) and it says "Photos are processed asynchronously and may not be visible right away". getRecord must not see a record change when it runs, as PHOTO_URL_FIELD hasnt changed yet

Comment: @Bobbygllh can I suggest you add this as an answer and mark it as the best answer for future readers?

Comment: I had this exact same issue and the solution that did help me was this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/292052/64395

Although i wasn't updating those photo in an async fashion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe i've stumbled upon the issue. I am using the UserProfile connect API class, specifically the SetPhoto method (documentation [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_UserProfiles_static_methods.htm)) and it says "Photos are processed asynchronously and may not be visible right away". getRecord must not see a record change when it runs, as PHOTO_URL_FIELD hasn't changed yet and therefore does not "refresh".

I employed a bit of a workaround that i would term a bit janky but for my use case it can be done without issues. I used the setTimeout() method so that it wouldn't run for 3 seconds, giving time for the photo to upload and put the refreshApex in there:

```
uploadUserImage({
                fileRecordId: this.newImage.ContentDocumentId
            })
                .then(() => {
                    this.showSpinner = false;
                    this.showModal = false;
                    this.saveDisabled = true;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        refreshApex(this._getRecordResponse);
                    }, 3000);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.handleError(error);
                    this.showSpinner = false;
                    this.saveDisabled = true;
                });
```

Potential issues is if it take longer than 3 seconds for the photo to upload through the setPhoto method of UserProfile then the getRecord would not run as it does not detect changes in the record (even though we are "manually" refreshing it)