# Force refresh of getRelatedListRecords

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, relatedrecord, get-record-notify-change

I am trying to get my `@wire getRelatedListRecords` to refresh when insert a Contact related to an Account. Currently when I insert a new Contact, my wire method does not return the new record to be displayed. I have tried both `getRecordNotifyChange` and `refreshApex` and neither seem to make a difference. Also it seems like `refreshApex` is being deprecated for non-apex usage (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_modules.htm&type=5&release=238). Here is my code:

`wireTest.html`

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="wireGetRelatedListRecords">
        <template if:true={records}>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <template for:each={records} for:item="rec">
                    <p key={rec.fields.Id.value}>
                        {rec.fields.Name.value}
                    </p>
                </template>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
    <c-wire-test-child child-callback={onResult}></c-wire-test-child>
</template>
```

`wireTest.js`

```js
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class WireTest extends LightningElement {
    
    error;
    @track records = [];
    @track contactData;

    @wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '00100000000000000',
        relatedListId: 'Contacts',
        fields: ['Contact.Name','Contact.Id'],
        sortBy: ['Contact.Name']
    })listInfo(result) {
        this.contactData = result;
        if (result.data) {
            this.records = result.data.records;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
            this.records = undefined;
        }
    }

    onResult = () => {
        console.log('am I getting here');
        refreshApex(this.contactData);
        console.log('should have called refreshApex');
    }
}
```

`wireTestChild.html`

```html
<template>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Insert Contact" title="Insert Contact" onclick={btnClick}></lightning-button>   
</template>
```

`wireTestChild.js`

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import {
    getRecordCreateDefaults,
    generateRecordInputForCreate,
    createRecord,
    getRecordNotifyChange
} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contact';

export default class WireTestChild extends LightningElement {
    @api childCallback;
    contRecordInput;
    contactId;

    @wire(getRecordCreateDefaults, { objectApiName: CONTACT_OBJECT })
    contactCreateDefaults;

    recordInputForCreate() {
        if (!this.contactCreateDefaults.data) {
            return undefined;
        }

        const contactObjectInfo = this.contactCreateDefaults.data.objectInfos[
            CONTACT_OBJECT.objectApiName
        ];
        const recordDefaults = this.contactCreateDefaults.data.record;
        const recordInput = generateRecordInputForCreate(
            recordDefaults,
            contactObjectInfo
        );
        return recordInput;
    }

    btnClick()
    {
        this.contRecordInput = this.recordInputForCreate();

        this.contRecordInput.fields.FirstName = 'Fooey';
        this.contRecordInput.fields.LastName = 'Test';
        this.contRecordInput.fields.AccountId = '001000000000000';
        this.contRecordInput.fields.Email = 'fooey@barey.com';
        this.contRecordInput.fields.LeadSource = 'LeadSource';

        createRecord(this.contRecordInput)
            .then(contact => {
                this.childCallback();
                this.contactId = contact.id;
                // I am assuming to notify the Account Id since that's where I am grabbing the related records
                //getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: '001000000000000'}]);
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Contact created',
                        variant: 'success',
                    }),
                );
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error creating record',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error',
                    }),
                );
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh wired service getRecord manually?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279516/how-to-refresh-wired-service-getrecord-manually)

Comment: @PhilW So I tried that previously but it had no impact

Comment: If you previously had `listInfo({ error, data })` like you do here, this is not compatible with `refreshApex`. You must use `listInfo(result)`, store `result` for passing to `refreshApex` and extract `{error, data} = result;` to access the error and data values in the wire result handling...

Comment: @PhilW just tried this, no difference

Comment: Can you update the question to show how you tried to capture the wire result then later use the refreshApex call, please?

Comment: @PhilW I have updated. Also I am reading that `refreshApex` is deprecated for any non-apex usage (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_modules.htm&type=5&release=238)

Comment: Thanks for updating. Nice spot on that deprecation (which won't kick in until next May, so this shouldn't be causing you any difficulties right now) and the switch to using `getRecordNotifyChange` (though I wonder if that would work with something other than `getRecord`?!).

Comment: Why are you tracking the `contactData` (which I think would be better called `relatedContactsResponse`) instead of the `records`? I suspect this may be your problem.

Comment: Ok I will try that.

Comment: Make sure you declare the property like `@track records = [];` so the LWC infrastructure knows this is going to be an array that needs tracking.

Comment: @PhilW no difference

Comment: That it isn't working is very odd - again, please update the question with your latest version of the code...

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: This *looks* right to me. Sorry, someone else needs to chip in at this point. Maybe there's an issue with the uiRelatedListApi?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible as of yet. What might work is to push created record reference to getRelatedListRecords list.

Comment: @CloudConnect can you expand on that in answer?

Comment: getRelatedListRecords  does not seem to support fetching new records created but what you can do is to update the list of records manually in js as a workaround. For explanation please see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGWAongZz2I&t=284s&ab_channel=SalesforceBolt

Comment: I appreciate that answer, however, I am not trying to update, this is inserting a brand new record having LDS detect the new record to update the table.

Comment: I checked with the product team and unfortunately, I don't have any good solution to share as of Summer '22. There's a "refresh view" module that may be in pilot in Winter '23 (forward-looking statement). It may address this is use case.

Comment: Thank you for closing the loop on this @POZ. If you can put this as answer I will accept it

Comment: Seems like you need your own apex method at least in the short term...

Comment: Agreed, which I would have done in the beginning of this, but this was carryover from another developer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from Spring '23 you now have access to the [RefreshView API (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_refreshview) that allows to cover this exact use case.

We've shared a basic example of the Refresh API in our [LWC Recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes) sample app (see Refresh View tab).

Back to your original question, you could write the following code. Note that these two components no longer need to be parent/child thanks to the Refresh API. They could be two different Lightning App Builder components.

### wireTest.html

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="wireGetRelatedListRecords">
        <template lwc:if={records}>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <template for:each={records} for:item="rec">
                    <p key={rec.fields.Id.value}>{rec.fields.Name.value}</p>
                </template>
                <template lwc:if={hasNoRecords}>
                    <p>No records found</p>
                </template>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

### wireTest.js

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import {
    registerRefreshHandler,
    unregisterRefreshHandler
} from 'lightning/refresh';

export default class WireRefreshList extends LightningElement {
    error;
    records = [];
    contactData;
    refreshHandlerID;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.refreshHandlerID = registerRefreshHandler(
            this,
            this.refreshHandler
        );
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        unregisterRefreshHandler(this.refreshHandlerID);
    }

    refreshHandler() {
        refreshApex(this.contactData);
    }

    @wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '0017d00001IwY00AAF',
        relatedListId: 'Contacts',
        fields: ['Contact.Name', 'Contact.Id'],
        sortBy: ['Contact.Name']
    })
    listInfo(result) {
        this.contactData = result;
        if (result.data) {
            this.records = result.data.records;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
            this.records = undefined;
        }
    }

    get hasNoRecords() {
        return this.records?.length === 0;
    }
}
```

### wireTestChild.html

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="wireRefreshAction">
        <div class="slds-var-m-horizontal_medium">
            <lightning-button
                label="Insert Contact"
                title="Insert Contact"
                onclick={btnClick}
            ></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

### wireTestChild.js

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import {
    getRecordCreateDefaults,
    generateRecordInputForCreate,
    createRecord
} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contact';
import { RefreshEvent } from 'lightning/refresh';

export default class WireRefreshButton extends LightningElement {
    contRecordInput;
    contactId;

    @wire(getRecordCreateDefaults, { objectApiName: CONTACT_OBJECT })
    contactCreateDefaults;

    recordInputForCreate() {
        if (!this.contactCreateDefaults.data) {
            return undefined;
        }

        const contactObjectInfo =
            this.contactCreateDefaults.data.objectInfos[
                CONTACT_OBJECT.objectApiName
            ];
        const recordDefaults = this.contactCreateDefaults.data.record;
        const recordInput = generateRecordInputForCreate(
            recordDefaults,
            contactObjectInfo
        );
        return recordInput;
    }

    btnClick() {
        this.contRecordInput = this.recordInputForCreate();

        this.contRecordInput.fields.FirstName = 'Fooey';
        this.contRecordInput.fields.LastName = 'Test';
        this.contRecordInput.fields.AccountId = '0017d00001IwY00AAF';
        this.contRecordInput.fields.Email = 'fooey@barey.com';
        this.contRecordInput.fields.LeadSource = 'LeadSource';

        createRecord(this.contRecordInput)
            .then((contact) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
                this.contactId = contact.id;

                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Contact created',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error creating record',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this @POZ can't wait to try it out

Comment: @POZ I'm trying to implement RefreshView API where the refresh event needs to be published from an Aura component and the event needs to be handled by an LWC. I'm pretty sure that I've got the LWC set up correctly to handle the event, but when I take the action that should trigger the event getting published I'm finding that I'm not hitting the handler in my LWC. I think it's likely that there's something wrong on the firing side. This is what I'm trying from the Aura component:  this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());

Comment: That's great news!  I was able to try it out with the above code.  I couldn't find 'Refresh View' in the latest LWC Recipes though, in the installed app or in github.  Have I missed it somewhere?

Comment: @MikeA this would the "DispatchRefreshEvent" recipe under the the "Refresh View" tab (sorry, the name is not obvious).

Comment: Is this example still valid? I get an error trying to use it
Error during LWC component connect phase: [Invalid contextElement. Must be an HTMLElement or LightningElement.]

I have not been able to get the RefreshApex to work with the getRelatedListRecordsBatch from lightning/uiRelatedListApi

Comment: The recipe still works and the RefreshView API is now GA. I guess that the error is coming from something else.

Comment: @POZ I think I know what the issue is, without LWS enabled you need to do things differently for the RefreshView API with Winter24 - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lc_refreshview_locker.htm&release=246&type=5

Comment: @POZ I have a component that does both updateRecord and createRecord, and for some reason the createRecord does not trigger the refreshHandler even with this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent()) called, but the updateRecord triggers the refresh even without dispatching the RefreshEvent(), does the createRecord method has to be called from child component same as in your example?

Answer (score 0):

Example from @POZ didn't work for me without returning Promise from the refresh handler.
I.e. it should be

```
refreshHandler() {
    return refreshApex(this.contactData);
}
```