# LWC registerRefreshHandler method throwing error via new lightning/refresh module

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-experience, summer-23

I am trying to implement the new lightning/refresh module into one of my LWC's, but am finding that I get a component error anytime I try to load my Salesforce instance after deploying.

**Invalid contextElement. Must be an HTMLElement or LightningElement.**

[image: Invalid contextElement. Must be an HTMLElement or LightningElement.]

The only thing to note is that this LWC extends another LWC of mine (messageServiceElement), but that LWC extends both the NavigationMixin and LightningElement.

```
import { wire, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { publish, subscribe, unsubscribe, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';

export default class MessageServiceHandler extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    // Message service code goes here
}
```

```
import messageServiceElement from 'c/messageServiceHandler';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import {
    registerRefreshHandler,
    unregisterRefreshHandler
} from 'lightning/refresh';

export default class patientRelatedList extends messageServiceElement {
    // other variables exist here
    @api recordId;
    refreshHandlerID;
    treatmentReportData;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.refreshHandlerID = registerRefreshHandler(
            this,
            this.refreshHandler
        );
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        unregisterRefreshHandler(this.refreshHandlerID);
    }

    refreshHandler() {
        refreshApex(this.treatmentReportData);
    }

    @wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '$recordId',
        relatedListId: 'Treatment_Reports__r',
        fields: [
            // Fields exist here
        ]
    })
    listInfo(result) {
        this.treatmentReportData = result;
        if (result.error) {
            // Logic goes here
        } else if (result.data) {
            // Logic goes here
        }
```

I know this is a new module, but just wanted to see if anyone could help me while there isn't much documentation provided.

**On a side note...** Ultimately, I am trying to refresh this component from an Aura component.
The Aura itself is a button that is placed on a flow screen. Once clicked, it will close the current tab (via WorkspaceAPI) and then publish a message via LMS. This message is then picked up by my LWC and some logic will then process.

What I'm finding is that using `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();` in the Aura component will not work at all. This was working in a previous implementation of these components, but after refactoring slightly due to a bug, it is no longer working to refresh my LWC.

I have also tried `eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();")` in my LWC after the message had been received, but this also doesn't work.

The LWC will only update after a browser refresh.

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens" >
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>
    <lightning:messageChannel type="channel__c" aura:id="channel" scope="APPLICATION" />
    <c:constants aura:id="constants"></c:constants>
    
    <div class="slds-clearfix slds-p-top_medium">
        <div class="slds-float_right">
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save as Complete" onclick="{!c.handleClick}" class="slds-button slds-button_brand"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

```
({
    handleClick: function (component) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find('workspace');
        var constants = component.find('constants').getConstants();

        workspaceAPI
            .getFocusedTabInfo()
            .then(function (response) {
                var focusedTabId = response.tabId;

                var message = {
                    messageContext: constants.PATIENT_COMPLETED,
                    payload: response
                };
                component.find('channel').publish(message);

                // Close the tab based on the focused tab id
                workspaceAPI.closeTab({
                    tabId: focusedTabId
                });
                
                var navigate = component.get("v.navigateFlow");
                navigate("NEXT");

                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            })
    }
});
```

Please note: Because there is no flow screen at the very end of the flow, this button is placed on the last possible screen I can possibly place it on. After this screen, there are a few assignment elements and an update element (which is the last element of the flow). I have to force the flow to the end by using the navigate "NEXT" method.

I see there is a similar question via this post, but for some reason I am getting the component error which I stated at the start of this post. If I can figure this out, then I may be one step closer (until I can figure out how to dispatch the refresh event via Aura):
[Trying to use Spring '23 RefreshView API from an Aura component to refresh wire data in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/400362/trying-to-use-spring-23-refreshview-api-from-an-aura-component-to-refresh-wire)

Comment: Given the description of what's going on, it sounds like there's a bug somewhere. Taking you at your word, that `messageServiceElement` does indeed extend `LightningElement`, it sounds like there may be a bug. As this is a beta feature, it's not entirely surprising. I'll see if I can reproduce it and get a ticket to someone, but you should do the same, if you have access to Dev Support, Partner Support, or some other support that can actually look into this.

Comment: Hi @sfdxfox, I have added the messageServiceElement class to my code to show how it extends LightningElement. I will see if I can get support for this too. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

Per SF documentation, there are different methods of registering your listener based upon the Lightning Web security settings (LWS vs Lightning Locker). see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-refreshview-api.html

Presuming Lightning Locker is enabled, your register call should look like this:

this.refreshHandlerID = registerRefreshHandler(
this.template.host,
this.refreshHandler.bind(this));

Alternatively, you can change your Lightning Web security setting as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I was troubled by the same issue and came across this query of yours. Finally checking this box worked for me:

Settings -> Session Settings -> Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components and Aura components