# Automatic reload of aura component if a record is updated asynchronously by a 3rd party application

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, aura, lightning-community

Let's say in my custom aura component, There's a spinner that indicates that we're still processing your record. What I want to happen is if that aura component is still open in a tab and a record that is related to that page is updated. I want to automatically reload the page. What I've tried so far are the following

1.) `setInterval function` - in my `doInit` method i have a `setInterval function` that calls a method in the controller class wherein I try to query the record to check if it was updated or not. Which doesn't work because it's not returning any data maybe because of the combination of `setInveral` and `callbacks`.

```
Controller

    setInterval(function(){
        helper.CheckIfRecordIsUpdated(component,event,helper);
    }, 
    5000);

Helper

function checkIfRecordIsUpdated(component,event,helper){
var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
var getNewStatus= component.get("c.getNewStatus");
getNewStatus.params({"recordId" : recordId})
getNewStatus.setCallback(this,function(response){
//DOES NOT ENTER HERE
});
$A.enqueueAction(getNewStatus);
}
```

2.) `force:recordData` - The issue with `force:recordData` is it will only detect the change on the record if i refresh the page.

```
<force:recordData
              recordId="{!v.recordId}"
              targetFields="recordField"
              recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdate}" />
```

Is there anyway for me to achieve this? Is this even possible in aura component?

Comment: Try Change Data Capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2) at the moment, LDS only detects changes done through Aura, LWC or the standard salesforce UI (which are lightning components indeed). That means that your change, being done through an API won't be detected. There's a feature salesforce is working on to overcome that --> see [LWC Force Refresh Wire getRecord](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260298/lwc-force-refresh-wire-getrecord)

For 1) you will have to use $A.getCallback --> see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm and https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/calling-apex-method-at-regular-interval-from-lightning-component/

Comment: Thanks!! It works now!